# Removing an EntityRelationship by its guid

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

when saving a modified account form on a MS Dynamics CRM 2015 on-premise installation I recently get an error:

**Dependency Calculation**

The dependent component EntityRelationship (Id=5288430f-7abf-e511-80cd-000d3a203473) does not exist.  Failure trying to associate it with SystemForm (Id=e284b20f-a66d-4019-9a96-83d6ce65847e) as a dependency. Missing dependency lookup type = PrimaryKeyLookup.

This message is not quite useful to me to fix the problem.
If I want to fix it, where should you look for ID "5288430f-7abf-e511-80cd-000d3a203473" and which toold would you use?

Answer (score 1):

You could try the CRM Metadata Browser. This is included in the tools folder in the CRM SDK that you can download for free. It is a managed solution that you have to install into CRM. Once installed you can use it to view information about your entities and their attributes

[MSDN Page for Metadata Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547411.aspx)

Select your entity; This will then list all the attributes that belong to the selected entity, in this case `Account`

You can then look through all the relationships and look for the `Metadata ID` property of the record. For example, here is the ID for the Primary Contact relationship

[image: Primary Contact ID]

You will probably have to examine all these relationships manually to find a match though.

Hope this helps